# Draw a line that can stretch like the Xcode assistant editor in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When it comes to drawing lines in Swift, most solutions out there are to override the drawRect function in a UIView, but I'm looking for a more dynamic way to draw a line.

I have a button, and I want to be able to drag from this button to the next. While dragging, I would like to draw a line from the starting point to the current touch location (exactly like how the assistant editor in Xcode works, when dragging from one thing to another), but I don't know how to draw a line while I drag from one button to the other.

So my question is: how do I dynamically draw a line from one starting location to the current "touch" location (just like the assistant editor in Xcode)?

Comment: Your first paragraph has the answer you need, combined with handling touch events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to get gesture events and draw a `CALayer` with `UIBezierPath`.

UIPanGestureRecognizer has some gesture states, in this case, we need to handle three states to draw the line. Let's separate the whole action into small pieces for more easier to figure out what to do.

Before the start, there is one thing you have to know.

```swift
// We can get current touch position via gesture recognizer.
let currentPanPoint = panRecognizer.location(in: self.view)
```

1. To get line start point and create a `CALayer` in state `UIGestureRecognizerState.began`.

```swift
case .began:
    panGestureStartPoint = currentPanPoint
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(lineShape)
```

2. Get line end point in state `UIGestureRecognizerState.changed` and create a `UIBezierPath`, assign the `CGPath` of `UIBezierPath` to `CALayer` to draw the line.

```swift
case .changed:
    let linePath = UIBezierPath()
    linePath.move(to: panGestureStartPoint)
    linePath.addLine(to: currentPanPoint)

    lineShape.path = linePath.cgPath
```

3. Remove the line from layout in state `UIGestureRecognizerState.end`.

```swift
case .ended:
    lineShape.path = nil
    lineShape.removeFromSuperlayer()
```

Combine the fragments above, here is the example code.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var dragFrom: UILabel!

    private lazy var lineShape: CAShapeLayer = {
        let lineShape = CAShapeLayer()
        lineShape.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        lineShape.lineWidth = 2.0

        return lineShape
    }()
    private var panGestureStartPoint: CGPoint = .zero
    private lazy var panRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer = {
        return UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGestureCalled(_:)))
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dragFrom.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)
    }

    // MARK: Selectors
    func panGestureCalled(_: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let currentPanPoint = panRecognizer.location(in: self.view)
        switch panRecognizer.state {
        case .began:
            panGestureStartPoint = currentPanPoint
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(lineShape)

        case .changed:
            let linePath = UIBezierPath()
            linePath.move(to: panGestureStartPoint)
            linePath.addLine(to: currentPanPoint)

            lineShape.path = linePath.cgPath
        case .ended:
            lineShape.path = nil
            lineShape.removeFromSuperlayer()
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

And it works like this.
[http://i.imgur.com/5JsFeoB.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/5JsFeoB.gifv)

If you wanna learn more details, this is the tutorial in Apple's Developer guides. [Learn how to draw shapes using Bezier Path](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html)

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Works perfectly! Thank you so much!