# Detect Gesture ended on different UI control using swift 3?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uikit

I have images on the screen (left and right) and i want to connect them with a UIBezierPath. I have followed this post on stackoverflow i can now draw a line from one image and on it's end gesture event (UIPanGestureRecognizer) i can draw it.

Article URl: [Draw a line that can stretch like the Xcode assistant editor in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44171027/draw-a-line-that-can-stretch-like-the-xcode-assistant-editor-in-swift)

But i am not sure how i can detect, if pan gesture has reached correct image on right side. Once it is detected then i can end the gesture which will finally draw the line.

[image: Left image connecting to same right image]

Also if I move the image will its line also move with it. Like image below 
[image: Image moved]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "cap.png"))
        myImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50)
        myImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true //Must be enabled for tap events
        view.addSubview(myImageView) //Add an image programmatically

        let myPanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.panGestureCalled(_:)))
        myPanGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
        myPanGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1

        myImageView.addGestureRecognizer(myPanGestureRecognizer)
    }

private lazy var lineShape: CAShapeLayer = {
        let lineShape = CAShapeLayer()
        lineShape.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        lineShape.lineWidth = 2.0

        return lineShape
    }()

    private var panGestureStartPoint: CGPoint = .zero

    @objc func panGestureCalled(_ panRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let currentPanPoint = panRecognizer.location(in: self.view)
        print(panRecognizer.state)
        switch panRecognizer.state {
            case .began:
                panGestureStartPoint = currentPanPoint
                self.view.layer.addSublayer(lineShape)
                print("pan started")
            case .changed:
                let linePath = UIBezierPath()
                linePath.move(to: panGestureStartPoint)
                linePath.addLine(to: currentPanPoint)
                lineShape.path = linePath.cgPath
                print("pan changed")
            case .ended:
                addLine(fromPoint: panGestureStartPoint, toPoint: currentPanPoint)
                lineShape.path = nil
                lineShape.removeFromSuperlayer()
                print("pan ended")
            default:
                print("UIPanGestureRecognizer default")
            break
        }
        self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    var connectionLines = [CAShapeLayer]()
    func addLine(fromPoint start: CGPoint, toPoint end:CGPoint) {
        let line = CAShapeLayer()
        let linePath = UIBezierPath()
        linePath.move(to: start)
        linePath.addLine(to: end)
        line.path = linePath.cgPath
        line.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        line.lineWidth = 4.0
        line.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
        line.opacity = 0.6
        connectionLines.append(line)
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(line)
        print(connectionLines.count)
    }

    func clearOldConnections(){
        //clear old
        for l in connectionLines{
                l.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
        connectionLines = [CAShapeLayer]()
    }
}
```

Comment: Show what you have done so far

Comment: I have written the code to draw the line. I start the gesture on the left image and line is visible and moving along with gesture as needed and when i end the gesture it finally draw the line on screen. Problem is I do not have the mechanism where i can say i have reached the target image and it is a valid line so draw it or else discard it.

Comment: GOTO: 1st comment; BREAK WHEN showingCode = TRUE;

Comment: @Knight0fDragon please see the code above in question. If you feel it is need improvement please say. Thanks

Comment: I thought you were doing sprite kit, this is all UIKit

Comment: Yes it is UIKit, i have just started doing iOS coding 3 days back. If you feel UIKit is not right for this approach and i need to use SpriteKit please let me know. What approach should i follow to achieve required solution. In Html JavaScript we have HoverOver/mouseDown event to detect if user has droped some thing on an element. Do we need similar solution here or it is different in iOS world.

Comment: your tags are wrong,  for UIKit you can use hitTest to find out what view you are touching https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest:withEvent: