# Swift - Creating a connection between two labels or button using blue drag line like in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, cashapelayer

I have managed to create the blue line like in Xcode but how would you recognise when the end point of the line is dragged and released above the other labels or buttons so a connection can be made?

[image]

Code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var label2: UILabel!


private lazy var lineShape: CAShapeLayer = {
    var color = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#5DBCD2")
    let lineShape = CAShapeLayer()
    lineShape.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    lineShape.fillColor = color.cgColor
    lineShape.lineWidth = 2.0

    return lineShape
}()
private var panGestureStartPoint: CGPoint = .zero
private lazy var panRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer = {
    return UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGestureCalled(_:)))
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.label.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)
}

@objc func panGestureCalled(_: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let currentPanPoint = panRecognizer.location(in: self.view)
    switch panRecognizer.state {
    case .began:
        panGestureStartPoint = currentPanPoint
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(lineShape)

    case .changed:
        let linePath = UIBezierPath()
        linePath.move(to: panGestureStartPoint)
        linePath.addLine(to: currentPanPoint)

        lineShape.path = linePath.cgPath
        lineShape.path = CGPath.barbell(from: panGestureStartPoint, to: currentPanPoint, barThickness: 2.0, bellRadius: 6.0)

    case .ended:
        lineShape.path = nil
        lineShape.removeFromSuperlayer()
    default: break
    }
}

func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {
    var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
    }

    if ((cString.count) != 6) {
        return UIColor.gray
    }

    var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
    Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}
}

extension CGPath {
    class func barbell(from start: CGPoint, to end: CGPoint, barThickness proposedBarThickness: CGFloat, bellRadius proposedBellRadius: CGFloat) -> CGPath {
        let barThickness = max(0, proposedBarThickness)
        let bellRadius = max(barThickness / 2, proposedBellRadius)

        let vector = CGPoint(x: end.x - start.x, y: end.y - start.y)
        let length = hypot(vector.x, vector.y)

        if length == 0 {
            return CGPath(ellipseIn: CGRect(origin: start, size: .zero).insetBy(dx: -bellRadius, dy: -bellRadius), transform: nil)
        }

        var yOffset = barThickness / 2
        var xOffset = sqrt(bellRadius * bellRadius - yOffset * yOffset)
        let halfLength = length / 2
        if xOffset > halfLength {
            xOffset = halfLength
            yOffset = sqrt(bellRadius * bellRadius - xOffset * xOffset)
        }

        let jointRadians = asin(yOffset / bellRadius)
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.addArc(center: .zero, radius: bellRadius, startAngle: jointRadians, endAngle: -jointRadians, clockwise: false)
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: length, y: 0), radius: bellRadius, startAngle: .pi + jointRadians, endAngle: .pi - jointRadians, clockwise: false)
        path.closeSubpath()

        let unitVector = CGPoint(x: vector.x / length, y: vector.y / length)
        var transform = CGAffineTransform(a: unitVector.x, b: unitVector.y, c: -unitVector.y, d: unitVector.x, tx: start.x, ty: start.y)
        return path.copy(using: &transform)!
    }
}
```

The code above replicates the gif animation. I used the questions below to create it if that helps.

[Draw a line that can stretch like the Xcode assistant editor in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44171027/draw-a-line-that-can-stretch-like-the-xcode-assistant-editor-in-swift)

[How to reproduce this Xcode blue drag line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43688437/how-to-reproduce-this-xcode-blue-drag-line)

I think the answer is in the above question but I can't get my head around it as it's for MacOS and not iOS.

Any help is much appreciated

UPDATE

From the really good answers given, I added the code below in AddedPanGesture(). This isn't the finish version of the code.

```
 case .changed:
        let linePath = UIBezierPath()
        linePath.move(to: panGestureStartPoint)
        linePath.addLine(to: currentPanPoint)

        lineShape.path = linePath.cgPath
        lineShape.path = CGPath.barbell(from: panGestureStartPoint, to: currentPanPoint, barThickness: 2.0, bellRadius: 6.0)

        let labels = [label2, label3]
        for labelPoint in labels {
            let point = panRecognizer.location(in: labelPoint)

            if labelPoint!.layer.contains(point){
                labelPoint!.layer.borderWidth =  10
                labelPoint!.layer.borderColor =  UIColor.green.cgColor
            } else {
                labelPoint!.layer.borderWidth =  0
                labelPoint!.layer.borderColor =  UIColor.clear.cgColor

            }
        }

    case .ended:
        let labels = [label2, label3]
        for labelPoint in labels {
            let point = panRecognizer.location(in: labelPoint)

            if labelPoint!.layer.contains(point){
                labelPoint!.layer.borderWidth =  2
                labelPoint!.layer.borderColor =  UIColor.green.cgColor
            } else {
                lineShape.path = nil
                lineShape.removeFromSuperlayer()
                labelPoint!.layer.borderWidth =  0
                labelPoint!.layer.borderColor =  UIColor.clear.cgColor

            }
        }
```

[image]

If there is a better way I would love the input.
Thanks!

Comment: When panGestureCalled    `.ended` state is being called, you are setting line (nil) & removeing it from super layer. You need to add logic here that if line is in rect of lable2 then 1. set line straight 2.  set line origin and frame

Comment: Why are you using square roots and trig functions, arcs, and transforms to draw a straight line from one point to another, plus start-point and end-point circles?  That code is about 500 times more complicated and confusing than it needs to be. Draw a starting point. Draw a connecting line of your desired thickness. Draw and endpoint. Done. No trig. No square roots, No transforms.

Comment: I looked at the link you posted, and that code is drawing a very complex "barbell" shape. I guess since it works it's fine, but it is going to be confusing unless you have strong trig and graphics skills. If it were me I'd probably just draw a couple of lines and add filled circles for the endpoints and call it a day.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Duncan. I rather keep it simpler too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just update the code for your convenience.

```
 @objc func panGestureCalled(_: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let currentPanPoint = panRecognizer.location(in: self.view)
    switch panRecognizer.state {
    case .began:
        panGestureStartPoint = currentPanPoint
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(lineShape)

    case .changed:
        let linePath = UIBezierPath()
        linePath.move(to: panGestureStartPoint)
        linePath.addLine(to: currentPanPoint)

        lineShape.path = linePath.cgPath
        lineShape.path = CGPath.barbell(from: panGestureStartPoint, to: currentPanPoint, barThickness: 2.0, bellRadius: 6.0)


        label2.layer.borderWidth =  hasDestine(panRecognizer) ? 10 :   0
        label2.layer.borderColor =  hasDestine(panRecognizer) ? UIColor.green.cgColor :   UIColor.clear.cgColor

    case .ended:
        if  (!hasDestine(panRecognizer)){
        lineShape.path = nil
        lineShape.removeFromSuperlayer()}
        label2.layer.borderWidth =   0
    default: break
    }
}

func hasDestine(_ panRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer)-> Bool {
    let point = panRecognizer.location(in: label2)
    return   label2.layer.contains(point)
}
```

Comment: Thanks E.Coms, it's pretty close in what I am trying to do. I'll try to figure out how to recognise when more buttons/labels are added. I have an idea based on Duncan's answer.

Answer (score 2):

`CGRect` implements a `contains(_:)` method that lets you tell if a rect contains a point.

You need to add logic that makes sure your starting drag point is inside a button, and that your ending point is inside a different button, using the frames of those buttons as the rects you interrogate. If you find that the user has dragged from one button to the next then your `.ended` handler (as mentioned by M Abubaker Majeed in his/her comment) needs to detect that and add a permanent link somehow. How you do that is up to you. You could use a separate shape layer to hold the lines that you want to persist, and an array of starting/ending points of the connecting lines, or various other approaches.

Comment: Thanks, Duncan. I will try this first.